# Getting rid of a hierarchical index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have just pivoted a dataframe to create the dataframe below:

```
date       2012-10-31   2012-11-30
term        
red       -4.043862     -0.709225   
blue      -18.046630     -8.137812
green     -8.339924      -6.358016
```

The columns are supposed to be dates, the left most column in supposed to have strings in it.

I want to be able to run through the rows (using the .apply()) and compare the values under each date column. The problem I am having is that I think the df has a hierarchical index.

Is there a way to give the whole df a new index (e.g. 1, 2, 3 etc.) and then have a flat index (but not get rid of the terms in the first column)?

EDIT: When I try to use .reset_index() I get the error ending with 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'view''.

EDIT 2: this is what the df looks like:

[image]

EDIT 3: here is the description of the df:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 14597 entries, 101016j to zymogens
Data columns (total 6 columns):
2012-10-31 00:00:00    14597  non-null values
2012-11-30 00:00:00    14597  non-null values
2012-12-31 00:00:00    14597  non-null values
2013-01-31 00:00:00    14597  non-null values
2013-02-28 00:00:00    14597  non-null values
2013-03-31 00:00:00    14597  non-null values
dtypes: float64(6)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: strange, I've just tried your data and reset_index() worked ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df= df.reset_index()
```

this will take the current index and make it a column then give you a fresh index from 0

Adding example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'2012-10-31': [-4, -18, -18], '2012-11-30': [-0.7, -8, -6]}, index = ['red', 'blue','green'])

df
    2012-10-31  2012-11-30
red      -4     -0.7
blue    -18     -8.0
green   -18     -6.0

df.reset_index()
    term    2012-10-31  2012-11-30
0    red     -4         -0.7
1    blue   -18         -8.0
2    green  -18         -6.0
```

Comment: When I try that I get an error message 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'view'' - I can paste the whole thing in (but its quite long...)

Comment: I just added an example to the answer.  you should post your code so we can make sure the data frame is as you describe it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: When I try to use .reset_index() I get the error ending with 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'view''.

Try to convert your date columns to string type columns first.

I think pandas doesn't like to reset_index() here because you try to reset your string index into a columns which only consist of dates. If you only have dates as columns, pandas will handle those columns internally as a DateTimeIndex. When calling reset_index(), pandas tries to set up your string index as a further column to your date columns and fails somehow. Looks like a bug for me, but not sure.

Example:

```
t = pandas.DataFrame({pandas.to_datetime('2011') : [1,2], pandas.to_datetime('2012') :  [3,4]}, index=['A', 'B'])
t

2011-01-01 00:00:00     2012-01-01 00:00:00
A   1   3
B   2   4

t.columns
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-01-01 00:00:00, 2012-01-01 00:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None

t.reset_index()
...
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'view'
```

If you try with a string columns it will work.